# Rails 4 not adding fingerprint to included "extra" Asset Pipeline manifest files on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I have a few extra manifest files in my app defined in `config/environments/production.rb` like so:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( www.js sessions.js embed.js www.css sessions.css embed.css )
```

These work fine locally in development mode, but in my custom Heroku staging environment, the `style_sheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` helpers don't add a fingerprint to the combined files, causing these assets to return a 404 error.

Here is an example of what's generated by `style_sheet_link_tag` for `www.css`:

```
<%# Look ma, no fingerprint! %>
<link href="//s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/stylesheets/www.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here is the file at `app/assets/stylesheets/www/index.css`:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require www/foundation_and_overrides
 *= require mediaelement_rails
 *= require mediaelement_rails/mejs-skins
 *= require www/base
 *= require www/icons
 *= require www/header
 *= require www/footer
 *= require www/home
 *= require www/help
 */
```

This behaves correctly in Rails 3.2.14, but not after upgrading to Rails 4.0.0. So what do I have to do differently to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to either copy the `config.assets.precompile` setting into `config/environments/staging.rb` or move it up to `config/application.rb`.

```
# Now in `config/application/rb` so it's loaded in both `production` AND `staging` environments
config.assets.precompile += %w( www.js sessions.js embed.js www.css sessions.css embed.css )
```

It appears that this problem surfaced because my staging app on Heroku loads settings for the `staging` environment:

```
# By running `heroku config`
RACK_ENV:  staging
RAILS_ENV: staging
```

Apparently, Rails 4 on Heroku runs `rake assets:precompile` for this `staging` environment (whereas Rails 3.2.14 loads from `production` no matter what). So the `config.assets.precompile` setting needs to be picked up in `staging` too.